# ASP.NET vs Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I was wondering why you would still use ASP over Silverlight, since with silverlight there is a lot you can do already. And you dont have to use css, jquery, js, html, etc.

Also with silverlight you can do a call to the database via ria service.

I can only think of 1 reason which is, that not every one has the plugin installed. But thats just a matter of time.

Just curious how you guys think of this subject.

Comment: I think that I would rather stick with css, jquery, js and html instead of silverlight & RIA services. No need for silver ball to tell what's going to live longer.

Comment: I have plenty to say on this subject, but it's all been said before... like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986121/silverlight-vs-asp-net-for-business) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485/asp-net-vs-silverlight) for starters...

Comment: @Arnis, what do you mean with whats going to live longer?

Comment: @slugster, i've read those topics, it's intresting. But not the discussion im trying to startup here, though.

Comment: What kind of app are you building? Intranet/Internet? If Internet, you wouldn't want some of your clients not to be able to use your app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734439/why-silverlight is another link where I asked the very same question. This is just to enrich discussion that is happening here.

Comment: @Yustme - i would break it down this way: for a *website* i would lean towards using ASP.NET plus its associated bits. For a *web application* i would lean towards Silverlight.

Comment: @Yustme don't pay attention. I just dislike silverlight. :)

Comment: @vc 74, although i am making an app in silverlight, but thats not what this discussion is about.

Comment: @Yustme correct word is `done` instead of `dead` I guess http://www.udidahan.com/2010/04/23/thoughts-on-microsoft-history-and-oss/

Answer (score 5):

@Andy almost answers it right.

The answer is simple: Silverlight is never going to be universal, **not ever** (the same is true of Flash). It may be that it achieves a very high level of availability - at least on personal computers - but even then its would be rash to assume that *everyone* has it.

So you have to make a value judgement - will sufficient of your target audience have (or be willing to install) the plug-in required to allow your application to run? There are good reasons to want to build an application with Silverlight - I'm not knocking the technology.

But - again - the simple answer is that using ASP.NET (or php or whatever) you can render plain HTML (with or without CSS and Javascript) and therefore will have as close to something that is universally accessible as it is possible to get.

Comment: The one thing that everyone fails to mention: when you do a **web application** you are generally selling it to a client, and you can then dictate that they have the Silverlight plugin installed. But as @Murph says, you get no such guarantee for openly available websites with normal punters browsing to them.

Comment: Similarly, when you're having software developed for internal use, market penetration is irrelevant.

Comment: what do you mean never going to be universal? Almost everyone has flash installed. There is so much content on the net using flash. Also, html still exists as of today, how do you know it will still be there over 10 years? ASM, BASIC, died too (or is just a matter of time) didn't they?

Comment: @Yustme. "Almost" is not all - no flash on an iPhone or an iPad. No flash on *my* mobile. No flash in some business environments. No flash *by choice* for at least some users (for all kinds of reasons). HTML isn't going away - especially not in view of the additional capabilities in the bunch of stuff referred to as HTML5. Put all of those together and you have good reasons not to abandon "ASP.NET" for Silverlight (or flash or Java Applets or...). Which is why you have to make a decision based on the specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

You've basically answered your own question there - not everyone has the plugin.  Especially in the business world where upgrading and adoption of new technologies can charitably be described as sluggish.

Silverlight's overall penetration has grown significantly over the past year, but that growth is not spread evenly across sectors.

As you say, it's just a matter of time.

Comment: And you've basically quoted me by saying i answered the question and how you ended your answer 'As you say, its just a matter of time'. but what do you think about it? Isn't this an alternative to asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a little bit more complex IMHO. Silverlight is brilliant for developing applications, so if you are doing an application you should consider it. A lot of what you do is more like producing documents and reports however. For such situations, Silverlight is the wrong answer. For one, it takes more effort to do it in SL than just straight HTML. The fact that you also lose a part of the audience using SL is then an additional reason not to use SL.

So, the answer you need to answer is "Is this an end-user application or a document". For apps use SL/Flex/GWT for documents use HTML.

Answer (score 0):

1. An app written in silverlight makes it harder to use the browsers built in functionality (tabs, history, favorites, etc.)
2. Silverlight makes the app slower to start.
3. Silverlight won't work on all platforms

In general, I think a lot of the arguments for "Desktop app vs. Web app" are going to apply SL.  You could very well ask the same question, "Why would you ever use silverlight instead of a click-once application?"

As an aside, silverlight isn't the first thing of it's kind.  Before it there was Java applets, flash, and even javascript frameworks to make rich client side interaction possible within a browser.  Currently Silverlight competes in the corporate sector with Adobe Flex, which also is showing potential.

In the end, HTML is always there.  All of these technologies ride in on HTML, so there is no danger of HTML becoming outdated anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

- Intranet and/or web site management -
  silverlight
- Publicly facing web site mvc / jquery/ css ... with media content with silverlight